# Twitter Search Api to find exact results

Tags: twitter

I am using twitter search api

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

I want to search for a word (exact match) and count the no of mentions or hashtags of that word (exact match).

I have tried `q="json" OR #json OR @json` but they retun something like json_decode or @json_dude but I want exact match.

Also, is there anyway to count the no of retweets without 'popular' search ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do exact search like this, there's no way.

You can do exact search only when you are not using `OR'

i.e. you can do `q="json"` but not `q="json" OR #json OR @json`.

But you can count the retweets by looking at field `in_reply_to_status_id_str`.
 Each `in_reply_to_status_id_str` represents that its a reply against a tweet , thus a retweet :)

Answer (score 0):

In the page you linked, see the paragraph of "Search Operators", the 2nd example is what you are looking for. It says you sould use "

just like in a google search.

Comment: I am mentioned that in my question that " " is not working in my scenario ( when I include @ and #)

Comment: mmm, well, it sounds correct because the exact word JSON is there, however i also tried to do something like: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%22%20json%20%22OR#json
but it didn't worked, probably twitter trim the spaces